# Как производить запись каждой строки в отдельную переменную?

Tags: python, pyqt5, список, qt-designer, pyside2

Возникла проблема с записью данных из файла формата **`.txt`**, я получаю данные из файла в зашифрованном виде, далее их расшифровываю и они вывожу.
Я хочу сделать так, что бы каждая строка в файле была четка предназначена к переменной, но как это сделать не знаю. 
Иными словами `пятая` строчка в файле предназначена только к переменой `line5`и ни как иначе.

**Код проблемного места:**

```
...
with open(directory_file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), key_priv)
        print(decrypted.decode('utf8'))
...
```

Всего в файле будет 28 строчек.

Полный код программы:

**main.py:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTCQJD5hQjarttH6UlMuCQDn0M-uudeL/view?usp=sharing

**crypto.py:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WOF20K3ulmFt0HorWf0Nj8CADTzUAX3l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Интересная задачка, а в словарь записать? или сильно громоздко?

Comment: @ZheniaKviatkivskyi слишком громоздко будет, хотя может это единственно верное решение. Вот хотел узнать кто, что предложит и покажет.

Comment: @ZheniaKviatkivskyi если хотите можете написать ответ на данный вопрос, если не будет решения лучше я приму ваш ответ)

Comment: Settings, объясните лучше что вы хотите сделать?  О каких координатах идет речь? Зачем вам это? Попробуйте как-то визуализировать ваши действия и результаты, которые вы хотите получить.

Comment: @S.Nick ошибся в слове, каждая строка из файла, должна соответствовать определенной переменной. Иначе говоря строка номер 5 записывается к примеру в переменную line5 и ни как иначе.

Comment: @S.Nick это нужно для проверки работ. В данной программе зашифрованные работы расшифровываются и проверяются на правильность выставленных ответов, ответы сохраняются в ранее созданном в данной программе файле, загружаются, расшифровываются и как я писал ранее сравниваются с проверяемыми работами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.answers = []                                                      # +++
        
        ...
        
        
    def app_key_task(self):
        ...

        with open(directory_file, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            
        for line in lines:
            decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), key_priv)
            print(decrypted.decode('utf8'))
            
            self.answers.append(decrypted.decode('utf8'))                      # +++
            
        print(f'\n -=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
        print(self.answers)                                                    # +++
        print(f' -=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- \n')

    def func_generate_keys(self):
        ...
```

---

В список `self.answers` мы записали какие-то ответы:

```
    self.answers[0] - это первая строка;
    self.answers[1] - это вторая строка;
    self.answers[2] - это третья строка;
    self.answers[3] - это четвертая строка;
    self.answers[4] - это пятая строка  (в ваших пояснениях это line5); 
    ...
```

Обращение к элементам списка:

Для обращения к элементам списка надо использовать `индексы`,
которые представляют номер элемента в списка. 
Индексы начинаются `с нуля`. 
То есть **`первый`** элемент будет иметь индекс **`0`**, 
**`второй`** элемент - индекс **`1`** и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Если развить тему словаря, то можно глянуть в сторону [Python – базы данных NoSQL](https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/python-technologies/izuchite-python-data-science/python-bazy-dannykh-nosql) Данные хранятся в виде словаря.